# MySQL 5.7 uses more memory than specified (in LinuxMint 19)

Tags: mysql, linux, linux-mint

On a 2GByte machine, Linuxmint 19 is using about 1,5GByte of memory in MySQL5.7 but is only adding a few lines in the database for an app which adds few lines per minute.

I specified key_buffer_size =512M in the configuration file 
    /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf

What can cause this behavior? For sure my machine has not enough memory with this, should MySQL not see this also?

I am using INNODB, does it have separate settings for MySQL5.7 for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To use more ram can be result of number of connections to the DB. Make sure all the connections are properly closed after execution and you can check number of process by 
`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` on MYSQL console. 
You can change the connections by,

```
set global max_connections = 200;
```

When you restart MySQL the next time it will use this setting instead of the default.

Comment: Thanks, but I only have 2 connections... one for SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST and the other for my program.

Comment: Also changed innodb_buffer_pool_size  = 32M and innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2 , but still 1,3GByte usage.

Comment: Also tried: performance_schema=0  and removed some MEMORY tables from my database (oeps)... but no change :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-use.html) of mysql where they have clearly explained about memory usage.